# How to find a grave in Barcelona?

Tags: barcelona, cemeteries

A relative of mine lived many years in Barcelona, Spain and died there. I am quite sure she is buried there too but do not know in which cemetery nor even how many cemeteries there are there.

I found some descriptions of Barcelona's cemeteries, such as Poblenou and Montjuïc at [The Culture Trip](http://theculturetrip.com/europe/spain/articles/a-guide-to-barcelonas-cemeteries/), and several others elsewhere, but no comprehensive list.

Where might I obtain a complete listing of Barcelona's cemeteries (preferably with officials to contact about visiting arrangements and other enquiries)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about ancestry and not travel.

Comment: I think visiting the grave of a relative in a foreign country is clearly travel and finding the grave is a problem with that type of travel that this site may be able to help with. The question isn't about ancestry, it's about travelling to a grave.

Comment: I am confused: why is it on-topic asking about how to find a specific monument (say the tallest building in a town or such) or a restaurant with a specific cuisine, while it is off-topic how to find the cemetery with a specific grave?

Comment: It's worth being aware that Spanish burial customs may differ from those of your culture. The coffin is initially placed in a hole in the wall (*nicho*), which is rented; when the family stop paying the rent, the bones are removed and placed in a common ossuary. I hope that by being forewarned, if this turns out to be the case for your relative it will not be a painful shock.

Comment: @PeterTaylor this is true but depending on family wealth and/or space available, the coffin may be buried in land. This place (or the _nicho_) can be purchased, at least in the past.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a company handling all cemeteries in Barcelona. Its name is [*Cementiris de Barcelona*](http://www.cbsa.cat/?lang=en).

From their website:

> Cementiris de Barcelona, S.A. is part of the B:SM Group. It manages the new cemeteries in the city of Barcelona, Montjuïc, Poblenou, Sant Andreu, Les Corts, Collserola, Horta, Sants, Sarrià and Sant Gervasi, as well as the two crematoriums situated in Montjuïc and Collserola. Its main objectives are to focus the running of the cemeteries and all their activities on the users, to improve personalized attention, to provide quality funeral services that involve the transfer the deceased persons to our cemeteries, and to disseminate the culture and the history of the cemeteries.

If you browse through it you can find a section *Services → Location deceased* in which a form is displayed so that you can look for a deceased.

I don't know how well this can work, but it definitely works like the place to start looking from.

If you know where in the city was your relative living, you can more or less guess where she was buried. However, as you see from the quoted text, there are not that many cemeteries in the city, so you can do search for your relative's name in each one of them.

I did a basic research on a very common Spanish name, [*Carlos Garcia*, in the cemetery of Montjuïc](http://www.cbsa.cat/localitzacio-de-difunts/?Cementiri=2&Nom=carlos&Cognom1=garcia&Cognom2) and got a nice page with 28 results

The page results are in Catalan, but it is not difficult to understand:

> Resultats
>
> Premi al damunt del difunt sel.leccionat, d'entre les 28 semblances trobades:
>
> Cognoms, Nom  Núm Pis Tipus   Agrupació

Which translates to:

> Results
>
> Select one of the decesead from the 28 matches that were found:
>
> Surnames, Name   Number   Floor   Type    Group

When you click the name, you get to a page with a very complete map on the position of the grave within the cemetery.

Comment: If you don't find it that way, try findagrave.com and interment.net which are also unlikely to have it but can't hurt to look.

Comment: FWIW, I searched several relatives and I found all of them.

Comment: @orique oh, nice! Was it accurate also to find the exact location of the grave?

Comment: @fedorqui Yes! But you may have to think a little if you were used to  hypocoristics -- in the search engine you need to write the name as it appeared in the deceased ID card. So searching by surname might be easier.

Answer (score 6):

You could always look for the deceased note, there's always a published note, paid by the familiars or by the agency.

This database holds up to 17K pages of deceased notes just in Barcelona, you might be lucky. They usually tell where the person was buried, prepared, or incinerated, and from there's, you're a Google and a call away for them to look to your relative in their files.

http://www.rememori.com/buscar/donde:Barcelona